# How to set primary key with duplicate values based on main primary key?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 3 tables in my data base "`countries, cities and address_book`"

Table : countries

```
country_code   (primary key)
country_Name
```

Table : cities

```
country_code   (primary key)
city_code (primary key)
city_Name
```

Table : address_book

```
country_code   (primary key)
city_code (primary key)
address
```

I need to set table `cities` like below

```
country_id       city_id   ciTy_name
IN               1         IN_city_name_1  
IN               2         IN_city_name_2
AE               1         AE_city_name_1  
AE               2         AE_city_name_2
```

1. But my primary key of `city_i`d in the table `cities` not allow me to update table with duplicate keys
2. Also when i update `city_id` in the table `cities`. i need to update `city_id` in the `address_book` based on the primary key `country_id`

Comment: use composite primary key `country_id+city_id`

Comment: Then you need a composite primary key, or a completely separate autoincrement primary key and a unique key, on country_id and city_id

Answer (score 1):

When your field referenced to another table's key, you should use [FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). This is suitable for `country_code` in `cities`

You also should remove `country_code` from `address_book`, because table `cities` already contains it.

How I would do that:

```
Table : countries
  country_code   (primary key)
  country_Name

Table : cities
  city_code (primary key)
  country_code (FOREIGN KEY)
  city_Name

Table : address_book
  id (primary key)
  city_code (FOREIGN KEY)
  address
```